# Understanding the subgroup generated by an element of $G$

Tags: group-theory

I was looking for a counter example to:

"Let $G$ be an abelian group with subgroups $B_1,B_2$. If $B_1\simeq{}B_2$ then is $G/B_1\simeq{}G/B_2$?"

After some research online I found the counter example using $G=\mathbb{Z}_4\times{}\mathbb{Z}_2$ with subgroups $H=\langle(0,1)\rangle$ and $K=\langle(2,0)\rangle$.

My confusion lies with what $H$ and $K$ actually look like. I understand that $H=\{0\}\times\mathbb{Z}_2$. But I don't understand K. Is it $\mathbb{Z}_8\times\{0\}$?

***** EDIT *****

I can now see that $K=\langle(2,0)\rangle=\{(\overline{0},\overline{0}),(\overline{2},\overline{0}).$

But how is:

$$K=\{(\overline{0},\overline{0}),(\overline{2},\overline{0})\}=\{(\overline{0},\overline{0}),(\overline{1},\overline{0})\}=\mathbb{Z}_2?$$

Comment: No, consider $(2,0)\in \Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_2$ and try $(2,0)+(2,0)$ there.

Comment: It would make sense to be $\mathbb{Z}_8\times 0$ because you want to be isomorphic to $0\times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subgroup $K$ is equal to $\{(2,0), (0,0)\}$. It is a cyclic group of order $2$, isomorphic to $H$. Now $G/K$ is isomorphic to ${\Bbb Z}_2 \times {\Bbb Z}_2$, but $G/H$ is isomorphic to ${\Bbb Z}_4$.

Comment: Ok, now I can see that $K=\{\overline{(0,0)},\overline{(2,0)}\}$ but why is $\{\overline{(0,0)},\overline{(2,0)}\}=\{\overline{(0,0)},\overline{(1,0)}\}=\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: @kam You are not using over-bars consistently. For a start they should be over the elements of the pair, not over the pair: the first means "mod 4" and the second means "mod 2". But when you get to the final thing you write you surely mean them both "mod 2", so it's not an equality, it's just an isomorphism.

Comment: @kam What do you mean? $\{(0,0), (1,0)\}$ is not equal to $K$, it is not even a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Let me edit it again

Comment: I've edited accordingly, but am unsure if I have used the notation correctly.